# Index Out Of Bounds on List.Contains

Tags: c#

A piece of code in the CMS I'm using (DNN) throws the following exception:

"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

With the stacktrace saying:

```
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)
```

It is an issue that only happens sometimes (I suspect it has something to do with the cache getting broken) and only in production. This means I can't consistently reproduce it. I'm mostly interested in how it might happen.

How is it possible that a call to 'Contains' triggers an index out of bounds?

**Extra info**

The code calling the Contains works the following way (I've simplified the code to make the important parts more readable. The links lead to the exact classes and linenumbers)

[*CustomUrlDictController.cs*](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/a142594a0c18a589cb5fb913a022eebe34549a8f/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/Urls/CustomUrlDictController.cs#L198)

```
 List<int> urlPortals;
 var cc = new CacheController();
 cc.GetFriendlyUrlIndexFromCache(out urlPortals);
 var boolean = urlPortals.Contains(portalId); // This is where the exception happens.
```

[*CacheController.cs*](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/a142594a0c18a589cb5fb913a022eebe34549a8f/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/Urls/CacheController.cs#L251)

```
void GetFriendlyUrlIndexFromCache(out List<int> urlPortals)
{
    urlPortals = null;
    object rawPortals = DataCache.GetCache(UrlPortalsKey);
    if (rawPortals != null)
    {
        urlPortals = (List<int>)rawPortals;
    }
}
```

*DataCache ([1](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/a142594a0c18a589cb5fb913a022eebe34549a8f/DNN%20Platform/Library/Common/Utilities/DataCache.cs#L703), [2](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/a142594a0c18a589cb5fb913a022eebe34549a8f/DNN%20Platform/Library/Services/Cache/CachingProvider.cs#L458))*

```
object GetCache(string CacheKey)
{
    return Cache[cacheKey];
}
```

*Full stack trace*

```
InnerMessage:Index was outside the bounds of the array.
InnerStackTrace:
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.CustomUrlDictController.FetchCustomUrlDictionary(Int32 portalId, Boolean forceRebuild, Boolean bypassCache, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, SharedDictionary`2& customAliasForTabs, Guid parentTraceId)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.TabPathHelper.GetTabPath(TabInfo tab, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, FriendlyUrlOptions options, Boolean ignoreCustomRedirects, Boolean homePageSiteRoot, Boolean isHomeTab, String cultureCode, Boolean isDefaultCultureCode, Boolean hasPath, Boolean& dropLangParms, String& customHttpAlias, Boolean& isCustomPath, Guid parentTraceId)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedFriendlyUrlProvider.ImproveFriendlyUrlWithMessages(TabInfo tab, String friendlyPath, String pageName, PortalSettings portalSettings, Boolean ignoreCustomRedirects, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, List`1& messages, Boolean cultureSpecificAlias, Guid parentTraceId)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedFriendlyUrlProvider.ImproveFriendlyUrl(TabInfo tab, String friendlyPath, String pageName, PortalSettings portalSettings, Boolean ignoreCustomRedirects, Boolean cultureSpecificAlias, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Guid parentTraceId)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedFriendlyUrlProvider.FriendlyUrlInternal(TabInfo tab, String path, String pageName, String portalAlias, PortalSettings portalSettings)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedFriendlyUrlProvider.FriendlyUrl(TabInfo tab, String path, String pageName, PortalSettings portalSettings)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider.FriendlyUrl(TabInfo tab, String path, String pageName, PortalSettings settings)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(Int32 tabID, Boolean isSuperTab, PortalSettings settings, String controlKey, String language, String pageName, String[] additionalParameters)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(Int32 tabID, String controlKey, String[] additionalParameters)
   at Ventrian.SimpleGallery.RandomPhoto.GetAlbumUrl(String albumID)
   at Ventrian.SimpleGallery.RandomPhoto.BindPhoto(PlaceHolder phPhoto, PhotoInfo objPhoto)
   at Ventrian.SimpleGallery.RandomPhoto.dlGallery_OnItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.OnItemDataBound(DataListItemEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind()
   at Ventrian.SimpleGallery.RandomPhoto.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: You probably are not looking at the line number correctly or maybe the code was optimized because it was built in release mode. The LoC that could/would throw that exception would be `return Cache[cacheKey];`

Comment: I'm not looking at any line numbers. It's the stack trace that literally says "at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)"

Comment: If you can use `Linq` try `urlPortals.Any(i => i == portalId);` instead of `urlPortals.Contains(portalId);`

Comment: If you have a stack trace from an exception you should **include the entire exception stack trace** in your question.

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: check with the debugger how urlPortals is initialized after  urlPortals = (List<int>)rawPortals;

Comment: It is an issue that only happens sometimes (I suspect it has something to do with the cache getting broken) and only in production. I'm mostly interested in how the 'Contains' call could ever cause an out of bounds exception

Comment: *"The code calling the Contains works the following way (pseudo-code)"* - Unless you post your real code, we will never know

Comment: The real code is in a big framework (DNN), I can post links to the different classes in github

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I've added links to the exact pieces of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a pull request open with a fix to this issue within DNN. We were experiencing this issue, and after making the change we have not seen this stack trace in our error logs.

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/pull/1932

Answer (score 6):

Since you only want to know how Contains can cause an out of bounds exception, here's how.

This is how Contains is implemented:

source taken from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

```
public bool Contains(T item) {
            if ((Object) item == null) {
                for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
                    if ((Object) _items[i] == null)
                        return true;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
                for(int i=0; i<_size; i++) {
                    if (c.Equals(_items[i], item)) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When size is incorrect somehow (race condition?) the exception will be thrown on the internal array access

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe. And it's not too hard to reproduce a race condition on the inner index access.

Comment: What other causes could cause the size to be incorrect? I don't think it's a race condition because when it happens, it keeps happening until the site's cache is cleared. (or is the race condition problem something that'd keep happening?)

Comment: @ThijsterHaar After a failure, the list inner state could be completely broken. Sorry, I'm not going to link the sources right now but I believe that if `Add` and `Remove` were called concurrently when list is at max capacity (and fail in the middle of the operation) the instance would be invalidated and stay broken forever.
That can be your case.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I'm not sure I understand the question. The code is running on an IIS website with Maximum Worker Processes on '1'. This means there is only 1 appdomain right?

Comment: I meant that if GetCache is running in IIS AppDomain but the call on some client then there is serialization going on which could cause the bug

Comment: I got this error when a row in the database got corrupted and produced the string: "C:\ 1�e". I think the adding of the item to the list may have caused some funky behaviour and updated the _size variable without actually inserting into the list.